# Debug Dump of a C# App

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, dump, adplus

I generated the hang dump of a c# app with ADPlus. When I tried to debug it with VS2008, it shows the following error message

No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed.

I have set the the symbol path of the .net application.

**What should I do to view the callstack of the c# app from the dump?**

Comment: do you have the pdb files for the binaries ?

Comment: Yes, I have the pdb files of the binaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-lab-1-hang.aspx

Visual Studio is not a suitable tool (VS 2010 is better, but it is only capable of analyzing .NET 4 dumps), you will have to learn WinDbg.